# Web scraping using NodeJS and Cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, request, cheerio

I'm trying to make my web scraper pull the titles of each article from a website (https://hypebeast.com/footwear), but I can't seem to get anything but undefined or some really messy errors. What am I doing wrong? Here's a snippet of my code:

```
        const request = require('request');
        const cheerio = require('cheerio');
        
        var titles = [];

        request('https://hypebeast.com/footwear', function(err, resp, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.title').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).attr('span');
                titles.push(title);
            });

            console.log(titles);

        });
```

Here's the error:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UtEU.jpg

Comment: please show your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This in not a Cheerio reading problem.
I open the website and I see the the DOM Structure is different.
So to find something you have to use the script like so:

```js
const request = require('request');
        const cheerio = require('cheerio');

        var titles = [];

        request('https://hypebeast.com/footwear', function(err, resp, body) {
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('.title').each(function(){
                var title = $(this).children("h2").children('span').text();
                titles.push(title);
            });

            console.log(titles);

        });
```